# Eternl not able to send ADA to Kucoin (Error 400)

Tags: transaction, eternl

I'm not sure where the problem is. I'm trying to send some tokens from my eternl wallet to my kucoin address. I've copied the address using the copy button from kucoin so I don't think it's because it's the wrong address.

I enter my password to sign the transaction, and it always fails.

Some transactions failed to submit (400)
failed:
723ae8bdfde988437f80f9ca4fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx533e18f84ac3dc8c2bb4
Bad Request
[object Object]

The hash changes, the error always the same.

I'm from Canada, and I know Kucoin has some legal issues here and new Canadian's can't get verified. But my account shows fully verified and I was able to send other tokens 2-3 months ago.

Thoughts?